# How do i remove reverse dulpicate list from a list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to learn the prolog, I want to fulfill the predicate below.

```
removereverse([[1,5],[5,1],[2,3],[3,2]],List).  ---> Input

what I want:

List = [[1,5],[2,3]].
```

mycode

```
removes([],[]).
removes([[N1,N2]|T],[[N1,N2]|New]):-
    \+member([N1,N2],New),
    removes(T,New).
```

Comment: How is this addressing the *reverse* part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

First, lets define a predicate to tell us if a list is duplicated within a list-of-lists. This counts a list as a duplicate if either it or its reverse exists in the target list-of-lists:

```
duplicated(X,Ls) :-               member(X,Ls).
duplicated(X,Ls) :- reverse(X,R), member(R,Ls).
```

Then we can say:

```
clean( []     ,    []  ) .
clean( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :- duplicated(X,Xs), !, clean(Xs,Ys) .
clean( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :-                      clean(Xs,Ys) .
```

That keeps the last "duplicate" found and discard those preceding them in the source list. To keep the first such "duplicate" instead, just change where the recursion occurs:

```
clean( []     ,    []  ) .
clean( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :- clean(Xs,Ys), duplicated(X,Xs), !.
clean( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- clean(Xs,Ys).
```

Another approach uses a helper predicate:

This keeps the first:

```
clean( Xs, Ys ) :- clean(Xs,[],Y0), reverse(Y0,Ys).

clean( []     , Ys, Ys ) .
clean( [X|Xs] , Ts, Ys ) :- duplicated(X,Ts), !, clean(Xs,   Ts ,Ys).
clean( [X|Xs] , Ts, Ys ) :-                      clean(Xs,[X|Ts],Ys).
```

To keep the last, simply change `duplicate(X,Ts)` to `duplicate(X,Xs)`. The former checks to see if `X` exists in the accumulator `Ts`; the latter checks to see if `X` exists in the tail of the source list (`Xs`).

Comment: hi, could you explain what does the exclamation mark mean in the "clean(Xs,Ys), duplicated(X,Xs), !." ?

Comment: The cut (`!`) eliminates a choice point: it means that backtracking into the cut causes the entire predicate containing it to fail. Other alternatives do not get considered. So having decided that `X` is a duplicate, we don't want to consider the alternative path where `X` is unique.